# WooCommerce Protected Download Folder Throws 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, permissions

I have updated WooCommerce to v3.8.1. I had it working fine with my previous version for years.

As we all know, there is an .htaccess file located in the woocommerce_uploads folder that is set to ‘deny from all’ which protects direct URL downloads.

My file download method in WooCommerce is set to ‘Force Downloads’.

My users cannot download their purchased products as they are receiving the standard ‘403 forbidden’ white page.

If I set my file download method in WooCommerce to ‘Redirect’, the products can be downloaded fine but they also become unprotected and can be downloaded from a direct URL link.

The woocommerce_uploads folder permissions is set to 755 and the .htaccess permissions is set to 644. All products in that folder are set to 644.

I cannot remove the .htaccess as I do not want people to download from the direct URL link.

WooCommerce should be working properly the way I have it set up, no?

I would really, really appreciate any help to figure out what I am doing wrong so that I can get this working as it should be.

Thanks,
-Richard

Answer (score 0):

you can use the option of woocommerce which let the users download the file with a dynamic link. you should use "X-Sendfile" sending method. or try to use "force download" method. 
if it does not work properly as before it is because tha update of woocommerce is not compatible with your wordpress theme version.use "wp-rollback" plugin and return to the older version

Comment: Hi Behrad - I have tried the other methods of send file. Is there something else I need to do in order to have X-Sendfile or Force Download to work properly?

Comment: no. as i mentioned you have to roll back to the older version of woocommerce. try the plugin that i introduce to you. and never update plugins without pre test in your local host

Comment: With all due respect, how are you certain this is the solution? It doesn't seem likely that a feature of such importance has a solution of only rolling back to another WP version. I would be inclined to agree if we had actually done some testing and found evidence but we haven't. Pardon my doubts but can we troubleshoot to know for certain that's the only solution?

Comment: ofcourse there would be a solution but you have to change in stylesheet of the main theme and it is so hard